# Reuse image in three.js textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load with three.js the same image in a large number (~ 1000) of bidimensional shapes but with different offsets in every shape.

I've taken [this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sha#webgl_geometry_shapes) from the official website and customized it into [this other demo](https://jsbin.com/jufoduteco/edit?html,js,output), with all my shapes and a random background texture.

The problem is that if I clone the texture once per shape the page eats a lot of RAM and it ends up crashing. 
You can see this in action by going in the javascript and changing the comments in the `addShape` function (you'll find the instructions in the code).

I've done some research and found some results, like [this open issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5821) or [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976365/two-meshes-same-texture-different-offset) where it's recommended to clone the texture; anyway nothing seems to work in my example.

Am I doing something wrong? It's changed something since these last posts about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I´m misunderstanding the problem, but why don´t you change the UV coordinates of the individual shapes to align the texture and use just one texture?

From [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Geometry.html):

> **Geometry.faceVertexUvs**
>
> Array of face UV layers, used for mapping textures onto the geometry.
> Each UV layer is an array of UVs matching the order and number of
> vertices in faces.
>
> To signal an update in this array, Geometry.uvsNeedUpdate needs to be
> set to true.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this approach now. I still think that cloning the texture shouldn't store again the entire image, but maybe it's only my limited knowledge in the field.
Thanks anyway!